# How do I put a placeholder for a column name in mysql python connector?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python, mysql-connector-python

so I know how to use %s but it doesn't appear to work for a column name.
my aim here is to get a column name (a roll number here) and use that to find information (how many days they attended)

```
roll=input("enter roll no.: ")
c1.execute("select sum(%s) from attendance", ("" + roll + "",))
a=c1.fetchall()
```

the table looks like:

```
date       | 11b1 | 11b2 | 11b3 |......| 11b45 |
2020-12-01 | 1    |  0   |  1   |......|    1  |
2020-12-02 | 1    |  1   |  1   |......|    0  |
2020-12-03 | 0    |  1   |  1   |......|    1  |
```

this doesn't work and seems to give me a random value
so how do I write that middle code? also why does the original code not give errors but still give an arbitrary seeming number?

Comment: The column that you're trying to get, what value does it stores? Days value? By the way, its always better to include an example of your table, the relation between what you're trying to do between the table and the code and the output you're getting now with an expected output. [Please refer to this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @tcadidot0 the columns just have 1s and 0s in them, except for the very first column which is a date. the columns I'm trying to call are all char(1) format

Comment: Actually the first edit was already good, let me help you with that.

Comment: @tcadidot0 thanks :)
so how would i use a placeholder for a column name?

Comment: I honestly misunderstood your question. I thought you're asking why the `SUM()` return wrong value. As to how to get column name in place for `%s`, I don't really have a clue, well, for python that is. Sorry.

Comment: What's the reason for concatenating with `""`?

Answer (score 1):

I will assume you mean the `columns_names`;

> *According to`Python 3.8`*
>
> > *By using `f string`*[¹](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/)

```
roll = input("enter roll name.: ")
a = c1.execute(f"select sum({roll}) from attendance").fetchall()
```

Comment: What  data variable are you passing?

Comment: it says ? is not defined

Comment: Sorry, its my fault. The values isn't iterated to use a placeholder. Now, it has to work. `f string` is new **Formating string** that has been developed according to `python 3.8`. it allows you to integrate the variable with string not to having crack out. I will edit my post and share with you a document article about the difference between it and `.format()`

Answer (score -1):

The names of MySQL schema objects - tables, columns etc - can be  interpolated using string formatting, by surrounding the placeholder with backticks ('`', ASCII 0x96).  See [MySQL Identifiers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html).

Using backticks prevents errors if the column name contains a space, or matches a keyword or reserved word.

However backticks **do not** protect against SQL injection.  As the programmer, it's your responsibility to make sure that any column names coming from outside your program (for example, from user input) *are verified as matching the column names in the table*.

```py
colname = 'roll'
sql = f"""SELECT sum(`{colname}`) FROM attendance"""
mycursor.execute(sql)
```

For values in `INSERT` or `UPDATE` statements, or `WHERE` clauses, DB-API parameter substitution should always be used.

```py
colname = 'roll'
colvalue = 42
sql = f"""SELECT sum(`{colname}`) FROM attendance WHERE colvalue = %s"""
mycursor.execute(sql, (colvalue,))
```

Comment: I'm sorry but this didn't work either :(
It gave me this error:
 " Unread result found"

Comment: That message appears if you execute a query but don't consume the entire result.  If you are using the cursor for another query before this one make sure you have called `cursor.fetchall()` or equivalent.

Comment: Or even better, test the code in isolation before integrating it with the rest of your program.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH
that worked perfectly!
if you don't mind could you explain to me what the f""" """ means?
but that worked!

Comment: It's an `f-string` - yet another way of formatting python strings - see https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals

Comment: @ru99 I was wrong to say that using backticks makes interpolation safe.  I've amended the answer to reflect this.